# Entity framework eager loading difference in EF4 AND EF6

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, eager-loading

What is the equivalent of EntityCollection.Load() in EF6? I'm currently reading a book for EF4 and in one of its sample, it calls a Load() method:

```
foreach (var contact in contacts)
{
    contact.Addresses.Load();
    Console.WriteLine(contact.Addresses.Count);
}
```

I'm using EF6 for testing and looking at the internet, this is what I found that works:

```
foreach (var contact in contacts)
{
    context.Entry(contact).Collection(c => c.Addresses).Load();
    Console.WriteLine(contact.Addresses.Count());
}
```

But if this is the equivalent, why is it so slow (very, very slow) compared to the first code when I ran the code using EF4? Both codes have LazyLoading disabled. I know there are probably better ways of coding to make it load faster but I'm just curious as to why the code for EF6 is significantly slower than that in EF4 (for this matter). Or is this not the equivalent code in EF6?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Why do you need to .Load()? This seems a very artificial scenario - hard to give advice.

Comment: I'm testing the code samples from a book. The first block of code was used to eager load contact addresses using the Load() method (which works in EF4). Now, I am trying to do the same thing in EF6 (eager load using Load() method), but with the current code I used (the second block), it is working but is too slow. I wanted to know why or is it even the Load() method version in EF6.

Comment: Does `contact.Addresses.Load();` not work in EF6?

Comment: I think it doesn't; IntelliSense won't pick it up and also, Addresses is of type ICollection<Address> for EF6 while EntityCollection<TEntity> on EF4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closer equivalent is probably:

```
context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
foreach (var contact in contacts)
{
    context.Entry(contact).Collection(c => c.Addresses).Load();
    Console.WriteLine(contact.Addresses.Count());
}
```

The `.Entry` method calls `DetectChanges` internally if `AutoDetectChangesEnabled` is set to `true` (which it is by default). Depending on the number of entities in the context and the number of `contacts` automatic change detection can be rather time consuming, especially if called many times in a loop. In EF 4 and `ObjectContext` there is no `AutoDetectChangesEnabled` flag and change detection isn't performed in so many EF methods as it is in the `DbContext` API when `AutoDetectChangesEnabled` is `true`.

Could you try if that improves the performance? It would interest me as well.

Comment: Hi Slauma - I've tried what you've written and yes, it did become very much faster. Tested along with EF4, EF4 still came out faster but at least now the difference is very little, almost negligible (almost). Though I still wonder why EF4 was faster. Thank you!

Comment: @g_b: Ah, good to know that it worked indeed! Automatic change detection is a tough part of `DbContext`. Here (http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2012/03/10/secrets-of-detectchanges-part-1-what-does-detectchanges-do/) is a 4-part series about it (part 2 lists which other methods aside from `Entry` are affected).

Comment: Yep, I already found that site once you mentioned in your answer about DetectChanges, will be reading it, thanks again!